# How to create two SearchViews in the Toolbar in Android

Tags: android, android-toolbar, searchview, android-search

I would like to have two search views inside a toolbar in one of my activities: the first for looking up the place of interest and the second for filtering by location.

The searchViews would be on top of each other always expanded. The top one would say "Search" as the hint. The bottom one would say "Nearby" as the hint. To the left would be the home button.

I have come up with two ways that could potentially work but I have encountered problems in both and I don't know how to resolve them.

**First Solution (Current)**

Here I have a linear layout and inside is a android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar, a view, and followed by a second Toolbar.

This is essentially what I want it to look like but the problem is that changing the hint text in onCreateOptionsMenu changes BOTH hints. I would like the top to say "Search" and the bottom to say "Nearby". It seems that because there are two toolbars, onCreateOptionsMenu affects both of them.

Code:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/search_container"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:background="#90909090"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/search_toolbar2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentInsetStart="56dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_action_bar_shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>`
```

onCreate:

```
Toolbar toolbar2 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.search_toolbar2);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar2);

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.search_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

OnCreateOptionsMenu:

```
SearchView searchViewTop = (SearchView)   MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id
            .search_top));
    SearchManager searchManager1 = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context
            .SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchViewTop.setSearchableInfo(searchManager1.getSearchableInfo(getActivity()
            .getComponentName()));
    searchViewTop.setIconified(false);
    searchViewTop.onActionViewExpanded();
    searchViewTop.setQueryHint("Nearby");
```

**Second Solution (Old)**

The second method involves putting a searchView instead of a second toolbar in the xml file. Although the second searchview isn't inside the toolbar, it can be made to look like it is. The problem I encountered with this is that the searchView not inside the toolbar looks different from the searchView inside the toolbar and how I would like it. When not inside the toolbar, the hint text is aligned further to the right and not directly underneath the top hint text. Any new text entered inside the searchview would be aligned correctly however. I tried customizing the style of the searchview to align it properly but was unable to find a correct method.

I was wondering if there is a way to correct either of my methods to make it work or if there is a new way to setup these two searchViews. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that when you call setSupportActionBar() for more than one toolbar, changes in onCreateOptionsMenu affect all the toolbars added. To solve this problem, I just called setSupportActionBar only on my top toolbar. For the bottom toolbar, I called in onCreate

```
toolbar2.inflateMenu(R.menu.search2);
SearchView searchViewBottom = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.search_bottom);
searchViewBottom.onActionViewExpanded();
```

Then handle all actions inside with setOnMenuItemClickListener.